# Swapping consecutive items of a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic-programming

I'm trying to write Prolog code that can swap two elements of a list, but only if they are **consecutive to each other**. That is,

```
conseq_swap(d, e, [a, g, d, e, f], X).
```

should give:

```
X = [a, g, e, d, f].
```

(d and e are consecutive.)

However,

```
conseq_swap(a, e, [a, g, d, e, f], X).
```

should always fail (a and e are not consecutive.)

**I can assume that an item appears in the list only once.**

I have the following code, which is actually working fine:

```
swap_conseq(X, Y, MainList, SwappedList) :-
   indexOf(MainList, X, Xpos),
   indexOf(MainList, Y, Ypos),
   Diff is Ypos - Xpos,
   Diff is 1,
   Xpos < Ypos,
   swap_ordered(X, Y, Xpos, Ypos, MainList, SwappedList).

swap_conseq(X, Y, MainList, SwappedList) :-
   indexOf(MainList, X, Xpos),
   indexOf(MainList, Y, Ypos),
   Diff is Xpos - Ypos,
   Diff is 1,
   Ypos < Xpos,
   swap_ordered(Y, X, Ypos, Xpos, MainList, SwappedList).

swap_ordered(Min, Max, Minpos, Maxpos, MainList, SwappedList) :-
   compute_lists(MainList, Min, Minpos, Pre, _),
   compute_lists(MainList, Max, Maxpos, _, Post),
   append(Pre, [Max, Min], Temp),
   append(Temp, Post, SwappedList).

indexOf([Element|_], Element, 1):- !.
indexOf([_|Tail], Element, Index):-
   indexOf(Tail, Element, Index1),
   !,
   Index is Index1+1.

compute_lists(MainList, X, Xpos, A, B) :-
   L is Xpos - 1,
   append(A, [X | B], MainList),
   length(A, L).
```

However, just by looking at the code, I can tell that this is a horrible way to do this - repetitive, inefficient - something only a Prolog newbie like me could write.

Any suggestions on how to improve this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Do read answers by [repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29844776/) and [Ludwig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29846746/). Those are good answers)

### Modified to remove both assumptions in old solution

```
conseq_swap(E1,E2,[E1,E2|R],[E2,E1|R]).
conseq_swap(E1,E2,[E2,E1|R],[E1,E2|R]).

conseq_swap(E1,E2,[A|RI],[A|RO]) :- conseq_swap(E1,E2,RI,RO).
```

Cuts (`(!)/0`) are removed.

```
?- conseq_swap(a,e,[a,g,d,e,f],X).
false.

?- conseq_swap(d,e,[a,g,d,e,f],X).
X = [a, g, e, d, f] ;
false.

?- conseq_swap(d,e,[D,A,G,E,F],X), A=a,G=g,D=d,E=e,F=f.
false.

?- conseq_swap(d,e,[A,G,D,E,F],X), A=a,G=g,D=d,E=e,F=f.
A = a,
G = g,
D = d,
E = e,
F = f,
X = [a, g, e, d, f] ;
false.
```

For the case where there are many possible pairs to swap, it output all ways of swapping only once. *The question assumes that there can only be one pair anyway.*

```
?- conseq_swap(d,e,[a,g,d,e,d,e,f],X).
X = [a, g, e, d, d, e, f] ;
X = [a, g, d, d, e, e, f] ;
X = [a, g, d, e, e, d, f] ;
false.
```

### Modified to remove assumption 2

If you want the query `conseq_swap(a, e, [a, g, d, e, f], X).` to fail outright, remove the first two lines in the old solution, which allows the original list to end up as output when no swapping is performed.

### Old solution (same output as the code in question)

This is the old solution written with the following assumptions:

1. The input does not contain any unbounded variable.
2. When no pair satisfying the condition is found, *output the input list as-is*, similar to what the code in the question does.

```
% Empty list gives empty list
conseq_swap(_,_,[],[]). 

% List with single element gives back the same list
conseq_swap(_,_,[A],[A]) :- !.

% If we found the 2 items that need to be swapped, we can swap them.
% We don't check for the rest of the list, due to the
% assumption.
% The cut at the end signals that the rule below do not need to be checked.
conseq_swap(E1,E2,[E1,E2|R],[E2,E1|R]) :- !.
conseq_swap(E1,E2,[E2,E1|R],[E1,E2|R]) :- !.

% We recursively check the rest of the list and append the result.
conseq_swap(E1,E2,[A|RI],[A|RO]) :- conseq_swap(E1,E2,RI,RO).
```

Comment: @repeat: Is there any drawback to using them? And if you have a better solution, why not post it? And if you don't want to post - please give me some idea how to improve it.

Comment: @repeat: Thanks. That is constructive criticism, compared to your first comment. For the case `?- conseq_swap(d,e,[A,G,D,E,F],X), A=a,G=g,D=d,E=e,F=f.`, I assume that the list is bounded - though it might be interesting to support it. For the second case, I agree that it is a bug.

Comment: @repeat: I realize that I implemented this based on OP's code, which actually return the original array on failure case.

Comment: These are good changes, making your code much more generally usable, more elegant and also easier to understand! +1!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a *logically pure* implementation of `conseq_swap/4`:

```
conseq_swap(E1,E2,Xs,Ys) :-       % use aux predicate w/dif-argument-order
   list_item1_item2_swapped(Xs,E1,E2,Ys).
```

Compared to `conseq_swap/4` the argument order of
`list_item1_item2_swapped/4` is altered, so
[first argument indexing](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=jitindex) is enabled. This can help prevent unneeded choice-points.

```
list_item1_item2_swapped([],_,_,[]).  
list_item1_item2_swapped([X|Xs],E1,E2,Ys) :-
   list_prev_item1_item2_swapped(Xs,X,E1,E2,Ys).
```

We thread an extra argument that refers to the previous list element through, employing a technique commonly called *"lagging"*. To see another use of this technique in action, look at [@mat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3966139/4609915) to some [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965054/prolog-find-minimum-in-a-list) about implementing predicates on Prolog lists.

The actual relation is defined by `list_prev_item1_item2_swapped/5`:

```
list_prev_item1_item2_swapped([X|Xs],X0,X0,X,[X,X0|Xs]). % stop swapping
list_prev_item1_item2_swapped([X|Xs],X0,E1,E2,[X0|Ys]) :-
   dif(X0-X,E1-E2),               % state logically pure "not-equal"
   list_prev_item1_item2_swapped(Xs,X,E1,E2,Ys).
```

Done! Now let's run some queries with [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) 7.1.37:

```
?- conseq_swap(a,e,[a,g,d,e,f],X).
false.                            % fails, as OP said it should

?- conseq_swap(d,e,[a,g,d,e,f],X).
X = [a,g,e,d,f] ;                 % succeeds, as OP said it should
false.

?- conseq_swap(d,e,[A,G,D,E,F],X), A=a,G=g,D=d,E=e,F=f.
A = a, G = g, D = d, E = e, F = f, X = [a,g,e,d,f] ;   % succeeds
false.

?- conseq_swap(d,e,[a,g,d,e,d,e,f],X).
X = [a,g,e,d,d,e,f] ;             % succeeds; only the 1st (d,e) pair is swapped
false.
```

---

#### Edit 2015-04-24

Here's a more direct, somewhat de-optimized variant of the code given before.

It *is* less efficient, but hopefully a bit *easier to read by humans*. 
As pure as the other variant.

```
conseq_swap(X0,X1,[X0,X1|Xs],[X1,X0|Xs]).
conseq_swap(E0,E1,[X0,X1|Xs],[X0|Ys]) :-
   dif(X0-X1,E0-E1),
   conseq_swap(E0,E1,[X1|Xs],Ys).
```

*Same* queries, *same* answers:

```
?- conseq_swap(a,e,[a,g,d,e,f],X).
false.

?- conseq_swap(d,e,[a,g,d,e,f],X).
X = [a,g,e,d,f] ;
false.

?- conseq_swap(d,e,[A,G,D,E,F],X), A=a,G=g,D=d,E=e,F=f.
A = a, G = g, D = d, E = e, F = f, X = [a,g,e,d,f] ;
false.

?- conseq_swap(d,e,[a,g,d,e,d,e,f],X).
X = [a,g,e,d,d,e,f] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (in SWI-Prolog) would be:

```
conseq_swap(D, E, L, Z) :- 
            append([A,[D,E],B], L),
            append([A,[E,D],B], Z).
```

Same queries, same answers:

```
?- conseq_swap(a,e,[a,g,d,e,f],X).
false.

?- conseq_swap(d,e,[a,g,d,e,f],X).
X = [a, g, e, d, f] ;
false.

?- conseq_swap(d,e,[A,G,D,E,F],X), A=a,G=g,D=d,E=e,F=f.
A = a,
G = g,
D = d,
E = e,
F = f,
X = [a, g, e, d, f] ;
false.

?- conseq_swap(d,e,[a,g,d,e,d,e,f],X).
X = [a, g, e, d, d, e, f] ;
X = [a, g, d, e, e, d, f] ;
false.
```

(Sorry if I'm not able to write so much like "repeat", but I'm italian).

Comment: Thanks for value my solution.  I want specify that my last comment was directed to other people, that could prefere to read more about this solution. It wasn't an attack to you! :)