# Find max integer in a list in prolog

Tags: prolog, max

I am trying to find the max number in a list. I know there are several solutions available online but I feel the best way to learn is to implement on my own.

I wrote the following code:

```
max([X],X).
max([H|T],Res):-
    (  H >= Res
    -> max(T,Res1), Res1 = H
    ;  max(T,Res)
    ).
```

Can someone point out my mistake? I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: One issue is that `Res` isn't instantiated on a query to `max`.

Comment: Try to "think different (Prolog)" ! What is the max of a list ? It's a member E of this list, and there is no other element of this list greater than E.

Comment: You'll need to introduce another variable to `max` and you can do this with an auxiliary predicate (which can just be `max/3` versus `max/2`). Here's a starter: `max([H|T], Max) :- max(T, H, Max).` This says, *`Max` is the maximum value of list `[H|T]` if `Max` is the maximum of the highest value in list `T` and the value `H` (last max value seen)*. Now, you need to define `max(List, MaxSeenSoFar, Max)` and now you have `MaxSeenSoFar` instantiated, so you can use your logical which compares `H` from `[H|T]` with `MaxSeenSoFar`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the max in a list - Prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798844/finding-the-max-in-a-list-prolog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't ensuring that `Res` is instantiated. You don't neccesary need a helper predicate to do that. You could make the recursive call before the check if `Res` is bigger than `H` where `Res` is the biggest integer of `T`.

You can use `->`, but you don't have to. But if you don't, a little bit more backtracking would be involved.

If you try to stay more on your route with recursion after the check, you'll need a helper predicate, as [lurker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980550/lurker) has suggested.

**Edit:** Since the answer is accepted now, here are the three suggestions implemented:

```
max1([H|T], Y):-  % with the -> operator, call first
    max1(T,X),
    (H > X ->
     H = Y;
     Y = X).
max1([X],X).


max2([H|T], Y):-  % without the -> operator, call first (this might be very inefficient)
    max2(T,Y),
    H < Y.
max2([H|T], H):-
    max2(T,Y),
    H >= Y.
max2([X],X).


max3([H|T], Y) :- max_(T,H,Y).            % with helper predicate
max_([H|T],HighestNow,Highest):-          % call after the test
    (H > HighestNow -> max_(T,H, Highest)
     ;
     max_(T,HighestNow,Highest)).
max_([],X,X).
```

Comment: hi i just posted another prolog question perhaps you will be able to assist me there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466467/prolog-appending-results-of-two-predicates

Answer (score 2):

Consider the code presented in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30302584/4609915) to related question "[Finding the max in a list - Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798844/finding-the-max-in-a-list-prolog)".

The code in mentioned answer is based on the [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`foldl/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=apply:foldl/4).

Here, I show how to do it with the meta-predicates `combine/3` and `reduce/3`. First, `combine/3`:

```
:- meta_predicate combine(3,?,?).
combine( _ ,[]    ,[]).
combine(P_3,[X|Xs],Ys) :-
   list_prev_combined_(Xs,X,Ys,P_3).

:- meta_predicate list_combined_(?,?,3).
list_combined_([]    ,[], _ ).
list_combined_([X|Xs],Ys,P_3) :-
   list_prev_combined_(Xs,X,Ys,P_3).

:- meta_predicate list_prev_combined_(?,?,?,3).    
list_prev_combined_([]     ,X ,[X]   , _ ).
list_prev_combined_([X1|Xs],X0,[Y|Ys],P_3) :-
   call(P_3,X0,X1,Y),
   list_combined_(Xs,Ys,P_3).
```

Building on `combine/3` we can define `reduce/3` as follows:

```
:- meta_predicate reduce(3,?,?).
reduce(P_3,[X|Xs],V) :- 
   list_aka_prev_reduced_(Xs,Xs,X,V,P_3).

:- meta_predicate list_aka_prev_reduced_(?,?,?,?,3).
list_aka_prev_reduced_([]   ,_ ,V ,V, _ ).
list_aka_prev_reduced_([_|_],Xs,X0,V,P_3) :-
   list_prev_combined_(Xs,X0,Ys,P_3),
   reduce(P_3,Ys,V).
```

Regarding the shape of their respective proof trees, `foldl/4` is similar to lists, while `combine/3` and `reduce/3` are similar to balanced binary trees.

Consider the following queries:

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

?- foldl(\X^Y^f(X,Y)^true, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 0,S).
S = f(7,f(6,f(5,f(4,f(3,f(2,f(1,0))))))).

?- combine(\X^Y^f(X,Y)^true, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], S).
S = [f(1,2),f(3,4),f(5,6),7].

?- reduce(\X^Y^f(X,Y)^true, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], S).
S = f(f(f(1,2),f(3,4)),f(f(5,6),7)).
```

`reduce/3` is based on `combine/3` and applies it until all items have been combined to one:

```
?- combine(\X^Y^f(X,Y)^true, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], S).
S = [f(1,2),f(3,4),f(5,6),7].

?- combine(\X^Y^f(X,Y)^true, [f(1,2),f(3,4),f(5,6),7], S).
S = [f(f(1,2),f(3,4)),f(f(5,6),7)].

?- combine(\X^Y^f(X,Y)^true, [f(f(1,2),f(3,4)),f(f(5,6),7)], S).
S = [f(f(f(1,2),f(3,4)),f(f(5,6),7))].

?- reduce(\X^Y^f(X,Y)^true, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], S).
S =  f(f(f(1,2),f(3,4)),f(f(5,6),7)).
```

Let's use it for getting the maximum integer `Max` in list `[1,5,2,4,3,8,7,2]`:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

?- reduce(\X^Y^XY^(XY #= max(X,Y)), [1,5,2,4,3,8,7,2], Max).
Max = 8.

℅ If you can't use clpfd, simply use is/2 instead of (#=)/2:
?- reduce(\X^Y^XY^(XY is max(X,Y)), [1,5,2,4,3,8,7,2], Max).
Max = 8.
```