# PROLOG: Summing up the series procedure

Tags: prolog

I have been trying to work on this problem that I found in a book, but am not able to make sense of it in my head. The problem asks me to use `series(N, Total)` for this procedure;
1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ... + 1/(N-1). Any help making me understand this problem would be appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Comment: No, as i said I didn't understand the question. I had previously done a sum of a list exercise, but this ones different. I started learning a week ago, so i am still a noob.

Comment: shouldn't it be 1/(N+1)? use your experience from the last excercize and now do the calculation with 1/(n+1) it is nearly the same i guess

Comment: Maybe a bit more context to this? How exactly was the question worded?

Comment: You should take a look at **numlist** and **foldl**

Comment: The problem is probably asking you to create a predicate, `series(N, Total)` in which, given the value of `N`, the value `Total` is equal to `1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ... + 1/(N-1)`. Does that clarify the question?

Comment: Yes I do get that, but when implementing it doesn't even compile for me.

Comment: Boris, that's all what's given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you want a predicate that evaluates this function:

[image: sum 1/x over x = 1..n]

In a procedural language, you'd write something like this iterative solution:

```
static double iterative_harmonic_number( int n )
{
  if ( n < 1 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("n");

  double r = 0.0 ;

  while ( n > 0 )
  {
    r += 1.0 / n-- ;
  }

  return r ;
}
```

Or this recursive solution:

```
static double recursive_harmonic_number( int n )
{
  if ( n < 1 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("n");

  double h = (1.0 / n) ;
  if ( n > 1 ) { h += recursive_harmonic_number(n-1) ; } ;

  return h ;
```

}

Both of which produce the same results for n in 1..10:

```
         iterative       recursive
         --------------- ---
f(  1 ): 1                1
f(  2 ): 1.5              1.5
f(  3 ): 1.83333333333333 1.83333333333333
f(  4 ): 2.08333333333333 2.08333333333333
f(  5 ): 2.28333333333333 2.28333333333333
f(  6 ): 2.45             2.45
f(  7 ): 2.59285714285714 2.59285714285714
f(  8 ): 2.71785714285714 2.71785714285714
f(  9 ): 2.82896825396825 2.82896825396825
f( 10 ): 2.92896825396825 2.92896825396825
```

Prolog is ideally suited for a recursive solution, so let's take a look at that. You have

- 1 special case that terminates the recursion (n=1), and
- the general case (n > 1).

We can express that pretty directly in Prolog:

```
f( 1 , 1.0 ) .     % the terminating special case
f( N , R   ) :-    % the general case:
  N > 1 ,          % - N must be positive (and greater than 1),
  N1 is N-1 ,      % - compute N-1
  f(N1,T) ,        % - recursively evaluate it
  R is T + 1.0 / N % - add that result to the current N's reciprocal
  .                % Easy!
```

Comment: @false - Fixed it. I must have edited out the important bits when I put it in my answer. My bad B^(

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what problem you are having.

A simple way to solve this problem is to define a recursive predicate.

You can work with fractional numbers using [`is/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(is)/2) and [`rdiv/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?function=rdiv/2).

This will sum from 1/1 to 1/(B-1):

```
series(B, B, 0).
series(A, B, Total) :-
    A < B,
    succ(A, A1),
    series(A1, B, Total1),
    Total is rdiv(1, A) + Total1.
```

How to read it:

- the sum (of 1/i) from B to B (excluded) is 0
- the sum (of 1/i) from A to B, where A < B, is 1/A plus *the sum from A+1 to B* (recursion). Note the order of predicates, they're slightly rearranged, because `is/2` requires all the arguments to be ground.

Example: we use it co calculate sum 1/i for i=1,...,3 = 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 = 11/6:

```
?- series(1,4,X).
X = 11 rdiv 6 .
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The question though wants you to work with two terms. I see three here?

Comment: then add a predicate `series(N, Total) :- series(1, N, Total).`

Comment: fractional -> rational. These rational numbers are specific to IF, SWI, and YAP.

Answer (score 1):

The answers presented so far can be imitated by using the [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) `foldl/4`.

Like [@mescalinum did in previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30912157/4609915) I will not use floats, but [arbitrary-precision rational numbers](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=rational).
Unlike with floats, the addition of rational numbers **is** commutative and associative. So when summing up rational numbers, any order of additions will get us the same result.

I propose using [lambdas](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord) together with the two meta-predicates [`init1/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30047316/4609915) and [`reduce/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30706698/4609915), like so:

```
seriesR(N,Val) :-
   init1(\I^E^(E is rdiv(1,I)),N-1,Rs),
   reduce(\X^Y^XY^(XY is X+Y),Rs,Val).
```

Sample query:

```
?- seriesR(4,Val).
Val = 11 rdiv 6.
```

---

To show that `reduce/3` can help speed up the summing up---even though it has some internal overhead of its own---let's run `seriesR/2` and `series/3` head-to-head for some *BIG* `N`:

```
?- time((series(10000,_),false)).
% 40,001 inferences, 2.805 CPU in 2.804 seconds (100% CPU, 14259 Lips)
false.

?- time((seriesR(10000,_),false)).
% 180,019 inferences, 0.060 CPU in 0.060 seconds (100% CPU, 3014245 Lips)
false.
```

---

#### Edit

Let's dig a little deeper!

The [implementation](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl) of [lambda expressions](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord) that we use incurs measurable performance costs. These costs will likely vanish in the future, once the appropriate optimizations are done.

For the time being, let's quantify these costs...

```
num_num_sum(X,Y,Sum) :-
   Sum is X+Y.

r_reciprocal(X,Y) :-
   Y is rdiv(1,X).

seriesR2(N,Val) :-
   init1(r_reciprocal,N-1,Rs),
   reduce(num_num_sum,Rs,Val).
```

Running `seriesR/2` and `seriesR2/2` head-to-head we get:

```
?- time((between(1,10000,_),seriesR(10,V),false)).
% 1,750,001 inferences, 0.389 CPU in 0.389 seconds (100% CPU, 4500790 Lips)
false.

?- time((between(1,10000,_),seriesR2(10,V),false)).
% 820,001 inferences, 0.137 CPU in 0.137 seconds (100% CPU, 5999216 Lips)
false.
```

In this example, using lambda expressions incurs a worst-case overhead of roughly a factor of 3. Significant? Maybe... but orders of magnitude less than using `foldl` instead of `reduce`!

Comment: Ah, a killer argument favoring rational numbers. It's valid, but you have not learned unum's, yet!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295356/how-and-where-to-ask-about-unums?s=1|0.4637