# Prolog taller than

Tags: prolog

What is the easiest way to find who is the tallest in Prolog:

```
height(lisa,1.65).
height(sam,1.70).
height(luke,1.92).
height(nicole,1.54).
```

I want to write

```
tallest(X) :- Y is bigger than other Y's
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
height(lisa,1.65).
height(sam,1.70).
height(luke,1.92).
height(nicole,1.54).

max_height(Person, Height, [[Person, Height]]).
max_height(P , H , [[P, H]|Tail]) :- max_height(_ , H2, Tail), H  > H2.
max_height(P2, H2, [[_, H]|Tail]) :- max_height(P2, H2, Tail), H =< H2.

tallest(X) :- findall([P, H], height(P, H), Bag), max_height(X, _, Bag).
```

There are ways to avoid writing `max_height` : [Prolog, find minimum in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965054/prolog-find-minimum-in-a-list)

Answer (score 5):

SWI-Prolog has some different ways to solve this problem, for instance by means of library([solution_sequences](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=solutionsequences))

```erlang
?- order_by([desc(H)],height(P,H)).
H = 1.92,
P = luke ;
...
```

or using library([aggregate](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)):

```erlang
?- aggregate(max(H,P),height(P,H),max(_,P)).
P = luke.
```

less sophisticate Prologs probably will offer setof/3 and last/2:

```erlang
?- setof(H:P,height(P,H),L),last(L,_:P).
P = luke,
L = [1.54:nicole, 1.65:lisa, 1.7:sam, 1.92:luke].
```

and still more basic engines, lacking setof/3, will offer

```
?- height(P,H),\+((height(_,L),L>H)).
P = luke,
H = 1.92 ;
```

Comment: The setof/3 only works if the height/2 happen to be sorted by height in the source?

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that `tallest(X)` succeeds if, and only if, person `X` is taller than all other persons, I think that a correct answer would be:

```
tallest(X) :-
    height(X, H),
    forall((height(Y, H1),
            X \= Y),
            H > H1), !.
```

First scenario:

```
height(lisa,1.65).
height(sam,1.70).
height(luke,1.92).
height(nicole,1.54).
```

```
?- tallest(X).
X = luke.
```

Second scenario:

```
height(lisa,   1.65).
height(sam,    1.70).
height(luke,   1.92).
height(nicole, 1.54).
height(bob,    1.92). % Bob is as tall as Luke!
```

```
?- tallest(X).
false.
```